# Casting float to int truncates rest, seem not reliable

Tags: python, c++, casting, floating-point

Being somehow surprised seeing things like this work:

```
float f = 10.25f;
int i = (int)f;
// Will give you i = 10
```

What is the gain?

OTOH 10.25 is quite a different thing than 10, which will be agreed, bad things might happen from such a soft conversion.

Which languages raise an error instead?

Would expect someting like: `"Error: Can't represent 10.25 as an integer"`.

WRT to answers given meanwhile: Yes, it might considered reliable the way a function like "round" is. But not straight WRT to integrity of data/information to be expected from cast.

Maybe a function "truncate" which defaults to behavior of "int" would make a better choice?

Comment: Why is this surprising? Moreover, what were you hoping for?

Comment: That's how C++ (and C) is specified to work, always has been like that.

Comment: Well, if you don't want strange behaviour, do not do strange things...

Comment: As a Python programmer, i can't see anything surprising..

Comment: Can you represent 1/2 as an integer? No - so why try?

Comment: Since the earliest programming languages of the middle of the last century it is common to allow conversion from a float to an int by rounding the value downwards.  (For negative numbers there are two ways of doing it: towards zero or towards negative infinity.)  So the behavior you find so surprising is nothing unusual.  Actually, I know of no language which allows this conversion and still raises an error in case the value has a fractional part.

Comment: @Alfe Thanks. Could you answer WRT to the benefits? As forgetting the rest might turn a bad thing is obvious, IMHO.

Comment: I see why this behaviour might be surprising, though. Python refuses to convert the string `'10.25'` to `int`. It permits converting the float `10.25` to `int`. If this seems inconsistent, OK, it's inconsistent. There are various string-to-int conversions in C and C++ that will accept the string "10.25" and convert it to the integer `10` (ignoring anything from the `.` character), so the reason cannot be *solely* an appeal to tradition. It would not be completely stupid to force you to use `ceil`, `floor`, or `trunc` from `math` as applicable.

Comment: @SteveJessop Thanks. Please post as answer again, it's hard to pick that stuff from comments.

Comment: @AndreasRöhler: I can't post it an answer since the question has been closed, but anyway it's not an answer since I don't give the reasons you ask for. It's merely a support for the question as not being quite so incomprehensible as people voted it to be. Unfortunately the rules on SO are that if 5 people don't understand your question then you're out of luck. And there are plenty of people who object to design rationale questions on other grounds too. I'm not one of them, I think that understanding design rationale is very much a programming problem! But you will encounter them.

Comment: I think the idea is that "conversion" also nearly always means to change the information, at least a bit.  You seem to vote for allowing conversions _only_ if they can be done without _any_ change in the information value.  I have the feeling here the majority disagrees.  In this case, the fractional part is forgotten by design.  Every programmer knows this (or should), so it is okay to change the information in the process.

Comment: I also think closing this question was too rash.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Thanks! Please post as answer, it's re-openend :)

Comment: In C++, we prefer `int i = static_cast<int>(f);`

Comment: @AndreasRöhler I have moved it to an answer, although the question already has quite a lot of answers.

Answer (score 3):

It is precisely the

```
(int)f
```

that tells that the programmer is aware of what he is doing, while silently cutting off the fractional part and storing the rest in an integer is forbidden in most programming languages.

By the way, it is not just that the fractional part is cut off. It is also that a floating point number can have a value so large that it can't possibly be represented as an int. Consider:

```
(int) 1e20f
```

Answer (score 2):

The statement `int i = (int)f;` explicitly says "Please take my float `f` and make it into `int`". This is certainly something I quite often find a useful thing to do - why wouldn't you want to be able to convert a float value from a calculation of some sort to an integer? The cast `(int)` will tell the compiler that "I really want this to be an integer", just like in C you can do `char *p = (char *)1234567;` - a typecast is there to tell the compiler "I really know what I'm doing".

If you do `int i = f;` or `int i = 10.25;` the compiler will still do what you "asked for" - convert the float value to an integer. It will probably issue a warning to say "You are converting a `float` to `int`", if you enable the appropriate warnings.

C and C++ are languages that require you to understand what you are doing, and what the consequences are - some other languages put more "barriers" in place to prevent such things, but that often means that the compiler has to add extra code to check things at runtime - C and C++ are designed to be "fast" languages.

It's a bit like driving a car, putting the car in reverse when there is a wall right behind, and stepping on the gas, will probably cause the car to crash into the wall - if that's not what you want, then "don't do that".

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the conversion is most definitely "reliable", as in "it will always do the same thing".

Whether you want to do that or not is up to you. In general the C/C++ languages are designed to give the programmer a lot of low-level power, and that means that the *programmer needs to know what they are doing*. If a float-to-int conversion surprises you then you need to think harder.

In fact, GCC has an option `-Wconversion` that will highlight cases like this. It isn't enabled by default, and is not part of `-Wall` or `-Wextra` (presumably because the behaviour is well understood and "expected" by most programmers), but the option is there if you need it.

Except that it won't give a warning, in this case, because your code includes an explicit cast `(int)`, so the compiler assumes you did it deliberately.

This gives a warning (with `-Wconversion`):

```
int i = f;
```

This does not:

```
int i = (int)f;
```

Answer (score 1):

Converting to an integer is useful in cases where you are working with complex data, but ultimately need to convert this data to an int to do something with it. Think of offsets in arrays, or pixels on a screen

Think of drawing a circle on the screen. There does not exist a fraction of a pixel (so the coordinates are ints), but you cannot calculate the coordinates of the pixel with just ints (sinus works with pi and other floats).